# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Workgroup Server 2011 upgrade

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

We've on-pre Microsoft Dynamics CRM Workgroup Server 2011 and we're planning to upgrade it by purchasing 5 more CALs.

Could anybody suggest what are steps/precautions I've to take ?

Answer (score 0):

- Backup your existing server.
- Start with a fresh install of 2011
- Use the Import Organization Wizard

This preserves your existing server while allowing you to test the migration to the new server.

You might give this a look.  It is a PDF published by the CRM User Group:
http://www.crmug.com/events/crmugdayone2012upgrading.pdf